# Urban erotica and authors

Tags: erotica, book-rec

What are some good examples of urban erotica? I am looking for a less explicit version of 9 and half weeks.

The reason for my interest is that I am very interested to take apart the elements of what we call 'chemistry'. It has been a mystery to me so far..how or why it happens( or not). So I wish to start a pet research project as a hobby and hopefully write some erotica in my spare time.

The other thing is that I am looking for a flavor of writing that appeals more to women than men. I am a male and I know what kind of erotica appeals to me:)

Comment: Questions here should relate to writing; I'm fairly certain this is off-topic.

Comment: Less explicit erotica? Erotica is explicit by nature. If it's not explicit, it's not erotica.

Comment: @neilfein; yes, this is a bad question. I'd -1 if I could.

Comment: Closed as per http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/a/892/26.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to define urban erotica. I know that I'm not familiar with that particular subset of the genre, and I am an erotica writer!

As for what flavor of writing appeals more to women, you're looking at more plot-driven writing, something with a story to it. PWP (Porn without plot) does have its allure, but for the most part, you can't go wrong with telling a good story.

For more information, you might want to check out the book **[How to Write a Dirty Story](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743226232)**, by Susie Bright.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not sure if I fully know what urban erotica means...but what I meant was a story between lets say..a wall street shark and a lonely artist. Or maybe the relationship between carrie bradshaw and Alexander petrovsky...taken further into the erotic realm(Please forgive cheesiness)